# Hibernate version column name exception

Tags: hibernate, grails

**Background** 
We have a vendor who upgraded their code from Grails 2.5 -> 3.3.2 and Hibernate 4.3 -> 5.

We also have custom code that looks at various custom tables which worked in the Grails 2.5/Hibernate 4.3 version of the application. After the upgrade, I now get the the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."VERSION": invalid identifier.
```

The HSQL shows it trying to select ‘this_.version as version4_0_0_’ as well as using the column in the where clause. A version column does not currently exist in the table.

Below is the original entity:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable", schema = "mySchema")
@ToString(includeNames = true, includeFields = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
class FinancialResponsibilityAgreement implements Serializable {
    /**
     * Compound key
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    FinancialResponsibilityAgreementId id

    /**
     * Agreement response
     */
    @Column(name = "myTable_AGREEMENT_RESPONSE")
    String response

    /**
     * Data origin
     */
    @Column(name = "myTable_DATA_ORIGIN")
    String dataOrigin

    /**
     * Activity date
     */
    @Column(name = "myTable_ACTIVITY_DATE")
    Date lastModified
}

@Embeddable
@ToString(includeNames = true, ignoreNulls = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
class FinancialResponsibilityAgreementId implements Serializable {
    /**
     * Term code
     */
    @Column(name = "myTable_TERM_CODE")
    String term

    /**
     * Student pidm
     */
    @Column(name = "myTable_PIDM")
    Integer pidm

    public FinancialResponsibilityAgreementId() {}

    public FinancialResponsibilityAgreementId(String term, Integer pidm) {
        this.term = term
        this.pidm = pidm
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I see package imports for grails.gorm.transactions that leads me to believe that this was another switch they made. However, I don't see any gorm package imports on any of the entity classes.

**GOAL**
I would like to avoid having to create new columns, using the existing activity_date column for the versioning and creating a compound id field.

**What I've tried**
I’m still learning Grails/Hibernate, but from what I’ve read and researched, I believe this is related to optimistic locking.

- adding the following to the entity (according to the Hibernate docs) still gives the same error.

```
@Version 
@Column(name = ACTIVITY_DATE") 
Date version
```

- adding a Grails mapping to define the version column name and a composite id, but those didn't change
  anything.
- just adding a column to the table called "version" resolved the exception with `this_.version`, but it now shows an exception for `this_.id`. This is likely due to the table not having an id column (which is a different story altogether). In my original Hibernate entity, I used an embedded id to combine two columns into a unique identifier.

Comment: Are you using GORM?

Comment: I believe they just switched from pure Hibernate to GORM in this new version. I see imports for gorm packages: grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional, grails.gorm.transactions.Rollback

Comment: However, I don't see any gorm references in the imports for the entities. How do I determine if the entity classes are actually using gorm?